# Django search with AND operator many to many relationship

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-queryset

This is my model

```
class MenuItem(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=False)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    image_url = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True)
    menu_category = models.ForeignKey(MenuCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}'


class Venue(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}'


class VenueMenu(models.Model):
    venue = models.ForeignKey(Venue, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    menu_item = models.ManyToManyField(MenuItem, null=False)
```

This is my view

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def search_menu_item(request):
    if request.GET.get('venue') and request.GET.get('search_name'):
        menu_item_filter = Q(menu_item__name__icontains=request.GET.get('search_name'))
        venue_filter = Q(venue__name=request.GET.get('venue').title())
        menu_item_search = VenueMenu.objects.filter(venue_filter & menu_item_filter)
        serializer = VenueMenuSerializer(menu_item_search, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

This is my serializer

```
class MenuItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    menu_category = MenuCategorySerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = MenuItem
        fields = '__all__'


class VenueSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Venue
        fields = '__all__'


class VenueMenuSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    menu_item = MenuItemSerializer(many=True)
    venue = VenueSerializer(many=False)
```

I want to search a single menu item information in a specific venue, as you can see in my query am querying the object but this query is returning me all the menu items associated with that venue including the one which I have searched but I want to have a single menu item which I am searching associated to that venue.

Comment: Remove `icontains`

Answer (score 1):

You get the correctly filtered `VenueMenu`s, but the related `MenuItem`s aren't filtered automatically because the filter is for `VenueMenu` and not `MenuItem`.

To filter the related `MenuItem`s in the serializer, you'll have to do a filtered prefetch using [**`Prefetch`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Prefetch) like so:

```py
from django.db.models import Prefetch


menu_item_search = VenueMenu.objects.filter(
    venue_filter & menu_item_filter
).prefetch_related(
    Prefetch(
        'menu_item',
        queryset=MenuItem.objects.filter(name__icontains=request.GET.get('search_name'))
    )
)
```

Also to improve this further, you can also select the related `Venue` using [**`select_related`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) to avoid doing a separate query just to get the venue details in the serializer. So all in all:

```py
menu_item_search = VenueMenu.objects.filter(
    venue_filter & menu_item_filter,
).select_related(
    'venue',
).prefetch_related(
    Prefetch(
        'menu_item',
        queryset=MenuItem.objects.filter(name__icontains=request.GET.get('search_name'))
    )
)
```

Comment: @ Brian Destura worked perfectly.Thank you